# What could this empty spacing under my listview item be?

Tags: android, listview, android-view

I extended the ArrayAdapter to inflate my own custom layout (it doesn't do too much else and the implementation is fairly straightforward). But I noticed there's this hairline of empty space between my listview items:

https://www.evernote.com/l/AM8w6ffsaQhGNJreixsY5fOwDbzTEL7Z73E

I've tried setting the height of the listview item as opposed to using `wrap_content`, there's no margin anywhere, and I'm setting the background color of the root view of the listview item so I'm having a hard time trying to figure out why that empty space is being added.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.event_row, parent, false);
      holder = new ViewHolder();
      holder.time = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clock_event_time);
      holder.title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.clock_event_title);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    ClockEvent clockEvent = mClockEvents.get(position);
    holder.time.setText(
        ClockUtil.halfHourIndexToHourString(clockEvent.getStartHalfHourIndex())
            + " - " +
            ClockUtil.halfHourIndexToHourString(clockEvent.getEndHalfHourIndex())
    );
    holder.title.setText(clockEvent.getTitle());
    convertView.setBackgroundColor(clockEvent.getColor());

    return convertView;
  }
```

And here's the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:background="@color/flatui_blue_1"
              android:padding="12dp"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="60dp"
              android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <com.compscieddy.foraday.ui.ForadayTextView
        android:id="@+id/clock_event_time"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_white_outline"
        app:fontface="montserrat_light"
        android:paddingTop="2dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        tools:text="7:00 - 8:00"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        style="@style/EventTimeTextView"/>

    <com.compscieddy.foraday.ui.ForadayTextView
        android:id="@+id/clock_event_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Early Morning Jog"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it's a `ListView` this probably is its divider. See [`dividerHeight`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#attr_android:dividerHeight), you can set it in xml or java to remove the divider.

```
android:dividerHeight="0dp"
// or
listView.setDividerHeight(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah - what a noob, I forgot the default styling of a dividerHeight exists. Solved by setting `android:dividerHeight` to `0dp`. Also could have added a style/theme.